# Why is @Size validator requiring a not null value using Spring? Edit: It is not due to a null requirement

Tags: java, spring

I know that `@Size` *does not* imply a value to not be `null`.
But in this project if I do annotate the attribute with `@Size(min, max)` when I try to submit an empty value it **acts** as a `@NotNull`

Here is the form:

Jsp form:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

[...]
            <form:form commandName="colloquioRicerca" action="colloquio_ricerca" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Cerca un colloquio</legend>
                    <p class="errorLine">
                        <form:errors path="codiceFiscale" cssClass="error"/>
                    </p>
                        <label for="codiceFiscale">Codice Fiscale del Docente: </label>
                        <br>
                        <form:input id="codiceFiscale" path="codiceFiscale" tabindex="1"/>
[...]
```

Domain class ColloquioSearch:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class ColloquioSearch {

@Size(min=16, max=16)
private String codiceFiscale;
[...]
```

Controller class:

```
 [...]
 @RequestMapping(value="colloquio_ricerca")
 public String cerca(@Valid @ModelAttribute ColloquioSearch colloquioRicerca, BindingResult br, Model model){
     logger.info("entered");
     if (br.hasErrors()) {
            FieldError fieldError = br.getFieldError();
            logger.info("Code:" + fieldError.getCode() + ", object:"
                    + fieldError.getObjectName() + ", field:"
                    + fieldError.getField());
            model.addAttribute("colloquioRicerca", colloquioRicerca);
            return "ColloquioSearchForm";
     }
[...]
```

Setted this way it is not accepting *null* values inside the form, I need to remove `@Size` constraint to make it work, and I cannot find where is the problem.

EDIT 16.06:
I checked for the parameter to be  `null` or not, and it is not passed as a `null` object, but as an `empty string` even without clicking in the input field before submitting.
Is the problem generated by the use of `this.parameter` when Spring builds the object? Because I read that using `this` you never pass a `null` value.
Thanks for the help, any further informations about documentation to read or something wrong I wrote is always accepted.

Comment: Are you sure it is `null`? Maybe the controller is receiving an empty String.

Comment: This also could come from your ObjectMapper.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes, I am just clicking submit without touching any input field

Comment: @AlexCiocan I did not configure any object mapper, I do not know if Spring got a default one (actually I do not know what is an objectmapper at all)

Comment: It would not depend on you doing anything, it is how Spring interprets an empty field. Run the program without the `@Size` and log the value of the attribute after submitting the form.

Comment: I added 
   logger.info("colloquioRicerca codice fiscale value : " + colloquioRicerca.getCodiceFiscale()); 
in the controller method, and it prints
INFORMAZIONI: colloquioRicerca codice fiscale value :

Comment: I am trying to guess if it pass an empty string or a null value.
Should it have printed "null" instead of nothing?
Eitherway, does the @ModelAttribute use setters to create the object or the parametrized constructor? 
Because if it uses the parametrized it passes values by using this, and using this never give a null value, so I am wondering if this could be the cause or not.

Comment: I checked...it Is not passed as null.